# OCI 19c - Parsing a PL/SQL statement that contains SELECT-FROM-INTO statements

Tags: c++, plsql, oracle19c

I have a need to parse queries using OCI.  For the most part - it is working.  However I ran into a problem today that I am not able to figure out.   For the time being - it looks like it's either a bug in OCI (currently using 19c 32bit) - or for some reason these kinds of statements are being ignored.

Whenever a SQL query contains SELECT-FROM-INTO statements - the entire query is ignored when OCIStmtExecute is invoked with OCI_PARSE_ONLY.  It doesn't matter if there are invalid entity names / syntax in the query.  I tried to find some additional info online regarding this particular situation - but I found nothing of use.

The query in question is below (the query is intentionally using garbage entity names to illustrate the strange behavior)

```
BEGIN
    SELECT ColumnThatDoesntExist FROM DerpyTable INTO ThisVariableDoesntExist WHERE YeahRight = :BindName;
END
```

The statement preparation code / execution code is below

```
   ...
   ... 
   if (OCIStmtPrepare2(connectionHandle
              , &statementHandle
              , errorHandle
              , command
              , commandLength
              , nullptr
              , 0
              , OCI_NTV_SYNTAX
              , OCI_DEFAULT))
              ThrowLastError(__FUNCTIONW__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    ...
    ...
    if (OCIStmtExecute(connectionHandle
              , statementHandle
              , errorHandle
              , 0
              , 0
              , 0, 0, OCI_PARSE_ONLY))
              ThrowLastError(__FUNCTIONW__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

In this particular test - OCIStmtExecute should be failing - however OCI_SUCCESS (aka 0) is returned when OCIStmtExecute is invoked.  Are there additional flags I should be using for these kind of statements or should I be looking at another approach?

I tried prepending the query with EXPLAIN PLAN FOR and invoke OCIStmtExecute with the default flag - but that just results in a missing-keyword error.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug in the OCI the return code OCI_SUCCESS (aka 0) is correct. It sent your statement to to the data base.  
Your statement is an anonymous block, indicated by BEGIN, and contains errors. You can do what you want, but you have to define the variable you select into. You have not done that so that would be 1 error. Also the INTO clause comes before the FROM so the statement should be "select...INTO...from", that would be error 2. Finally if it is true the column you select actually does not that will also generate a "compile" time error, that would be error 3. Also I believe  EXPLAIN PLAN for an anonymous block, is also invalid, but it been a long time since I ran into it.  
But you can try the following:
declare
ThisVariableDoesntExist varchar2(50),   -- or the correct data type
begin
select columnthatdoesntexist
into thisvariabledoesntexist
from derpytable
where yeahright = :bindname;
end;

Note: As an anonymous block the above should run (if the column actually exists). However, you **will not** get output. You may wish to add

```
dbms_output.put_line('Value=' || ThisVariableDoesntExist);
```

Oracle object names are not case sensitive and echoed back form Oracle will be folded to upper case, so it bast to avoid CamelCase and instead use snake_case.

Comment: Returning OCI_SUCCESS here seems quite strange to be honest.   The syntax errors were intentional to try and get an error back from the database (including the undefined variable).  

Any other anonymous block of SQL is validated correctly when invoking OCIStmtExecute with OCI_PARSE_ONLY (and returns syntax errors if there are any).  The only time this doesn't happen is if there are any SELECT-INTO-FROM statements within that block of SQL.